# How to insert line breaks in HTML documents using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a web service, and I want to return the data as XHTML. Because it's data, not markup, I want to keep it very clean - no extra `<div>`s or `<span>`s. However, as a convenience to developers, I'd also like to make the returned data reasonably readable in a browser. To do so, I'm thinking a good way to go about it would be to use CSS.

The thing I specifically want to do is to insert linebreaks at certain places. I'm aware of `display: block`, but it doesn't really work in the situation I'm trying to handle now - a `form` with `<input>` fields. Something like this:

```
<form>
  Thingy 1: <input class="a" type="text" name="one" />
  Thingy 2: <input class="a" type="text" name="two" />
  Thingy 3: <input class="b" type="checkbox" name="three" />
  Thingy 4: <input class="b" type="checkbox" name="four" />
</form>
```

I'd like it to render so that each label displays on the same line as the corresponding input field. I've tried this:

```css
input.a:after { content: "\a" }
```

But that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It'd be best to wrap all of your elements in label elements, then apply css to the labels. The :before and :after pseudo classes are not completely supported in a consistent way.

Label tags have a lot of advantages including increased accessibility (on multiple levels) and more.

```
<label>
    Thingy one: <input type="text" name="one">;
</label>
```

then use CSS on your label elements...

```css
label {display:block;clear:both;}
```

Comment: I had hoped to avoid the extra wrapping element, as the primary consumer of this page is software, not humans. But it looks like it's necessary.

Comment: All the better for software to have consistent start and stop indicators.

Comment: (You don't need the for="one" when you wrap the label around the input element.)

Comment: Drop the `for="one"` and `id="one"`, it's totally unnecessary and gets in the way because it's already got a `name` defined.

Comment: downvoted cause everyone is free to choose which solution they apply. sometimes another solution is not applicable or not accepted by the client or project manager for some reason.

Answer (score 42):

Form controls are treated specially by browsers, so a lot of things don't necessarily work as they should.  One of these things is generated content - it doesn't work for form controls.  Instead, wrap the labels in `<label>` and use `label:before { content: '\a' ; white-space: pre; }`.  You can also do it by floating everything and adding `clear: left` to the `<label>` elements.

Comment: when having big words `white-space: pre-line` or no `white-space: pre-wrap` worked for me, not sure about cross-browsing experience tho :)

Comment: Why is \a a newline character (I see it works but cant find any docs about it.)

Comment: @SamGoody it is mentioned in this W3C document http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space although they don't tell why they chose \A instead of \N or \R...

Comment: A backslash followed by a hexadecimal number is interpreted as a character reference.  `A` is the tenth character in Unicode, which is the line feed character.

Comment: @AlexisWilke To add to what Jim explained: A = 10 in hexadecimal (like 0xA) and char 10 of Unicode is the newline. They didn't choose explicitly choose `\a` over `\n`.

Comment: The link that Alexis provided no longer works.

Updated links: 1) https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/syndata.html#strings , 2) https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/generate.html#x16

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you've got a bunch of form items you'd like to show in a list, right? Hmm... if only those HTML spec guys had thought to include markup to handle a list of items...

I'd recommend you set it up like this:

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li><label>Thingy 1:</label><input class="a" type="text" name="one" /></li>
    <li><label>Thingy 1:</label><input class="a" type="text" name="one" /></li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

Then the CSS gets a lot easier.

Comment: Don't forget your label "for" attributes, if you omit them there is no point to using the label in the first place since it's not related to the input element in any way.

Comment: To follow up, you may also nest the input (or select etc.) element inside the label and safely omit the "for" attribute.

Comment: Sarcasm on SO... me no likey.

Answer (score 4):

the following would give you the newlines. It would also put extra spaces out in front though... you'd have to mess up your source indentation by removing the tabbing.

```css
form { white-space: pre }
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to specify a XSLT template within your XML that (some) browsers will process allowing you to include presentation with mark-up, CSS, colors etc. that shouldn't affect consumers of the web service.

Once in XHTML you could simply add some padding around the elements with CSS, e.g.

form input.a { margin-bottom: 1em }

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
   <label>Thingy 1: <input class="a" type="text" name="one" /></label>
   <label>Thingy 2: <input class="a" type="text" name="two" /></label>
   <label>Thingy 3: <input class="b" type="checkbox" name="three" /></label>
   <label>Thingy 4: <input class="b" type="checkbox" name="four" /></label>
</form>
```

and the following css

```
form label { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
label, input { float: left; }
label { clear:left; }
</style>

<form>
    <label>thing 1:</label><input />
    <label>thing 2:</label><input />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret is to surround your whole thingie, label and widget, in a span whose class does the block and clear:

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  .lb {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
  }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<form>
  <span class="lb">Thingy 1: <input class="a" type="text" name="one" /></span>
  <span class="lb">Thingy 2: <input class="a" type="text" name="two" /></span>
  <span class="lb">Thingy 3: <input class="b" type="checkbox" name="three" /></span>
  <span class="lb">Thingy 4: <input class="b" type="checkbox" name="four" /></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Right concept, but the "label" element is more semantically correct.

Comment: plus, the whole difference between <span> and <div> is that spans are inline elements, divs are block elements. If you're going to abuse spans this way, just use a div.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John Millikin. You can add in `<span>` tags or something around each line with a CSS class defined, then make them display:block if necessary. The only other way I can think to do this is to make the `<input>` an inline-block and make them emit "very large" padding-right, which would make the inline content wrap down.

Even so, your best bet is to logically group the data up in `<span>` tags (or similar) to indicate that that data belongs together (and then let the CSS do the positioning).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS clear element is probably what you are looking for the get linebreaks.
Something along:

> #login form input {
>     clear: both;
>    }

will make sure the no other floating elements are left to either side of you input fields.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_clear.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript options are all over complicating things. Do as Jon Galloway or daniels0xff suggested.

Comment: It's not a real answer, but a comment.

Comment: Comments did not exist when I wrote this over a year ago.

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript. If you're using the jQuery library, try something like this:

```
$("input.a").after("<br/>")
```

Or whatever you need.

Comment: Never rely on javascript to do what html/css can easily do because there is no graceful degradation.

Comment: Always have to rely on js, IF-AND-ONLY-IF your code is generated by some other framework or library. Otherwise we can put any html tags wherever we want :)