# User stylesheet declaration for button overwrites custom CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I want to insert a line break after the third button in the snippet below. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849/how-to-insert-line-breaks-in-html-documents-using-css/66000#66000) trick and wanted to use it but it doesn't work because my button doesn't accept `display: inline` and keeps the user agent style of `display: inline-block` no matter what (no important and no more and more specific selector will help). Does anyone know why this is? If I instead use the trick on the a tag, it works perfectly fine.

I know I could do the line-break as well with Flexbox if I would insert a div but I can't easily change the markup.

```css
.wrap .button-third {
    display: inline;
}

.button-third:after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
/*

.first-link {
    display: inline;
}
.first-link:after {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
 */
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="button-first"> Button 1</button>
  <button class="button-second">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button-third">Button 3</button>
      
  <a href="" class="first-link">Link 1</a>
  <a href="" class="second-link">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead of button, input type button.

```css
.wrap .button-third {
    display: block;
}

.button-third:after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
/*

.first-link {
    display: inline;
}
.first-link:after {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
 */
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type='button' class="button-first" value='Button 1'>
  <input type='button' class="button-second" value='Button 2'>
  <input type='button' class="button-third" value='Button 3'>
      
  <a href="" class="first-link">Link 1</a>
  <a href="" class="second-link">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried it and unfortunately the issue still remains. Also this would require me to change the markup as well.

Comment: @marlisa check my answer, is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: No, I would like to have the button 3 still on the same line as buttons 1 and 2 and the line break after button 3. I think `display: block` won't help me with this. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now by adding the line break with a before on the first link. Achieves the same result. I wonder why I didn't see this most simple solution before! I'd however still be interested if someone knows why the user agent stylesheet overwrites my declaration.

```css
.wrap .first-link {
    display: inline;
}

.first-link:before {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="button-first"> Button 1</button>
  <button class="button-second">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button-third">Button 3</button>
      
  <a href="" class="first-link">Link 1</a>
  <a href="" class="second-link">Link 2</a>
</div>
```